# Changing the default page in new tab on Firefox 3.5

Tags: firefox

I have Firefox 3.5.7 and after I installed a toolbar, whenever I open a new tab it opens with their website instead of a blank page. I uninstalled the toolbar and it still appears.

Where do I go to change that. From regedit?
Or some hidden place in Firefox?

Answer (score 6):

1. Type in **about:config**, in the location bar, that is the search field in your web browser you use to navigate to a website.
2. Click OK on the warning message that appears.
3. In the search bar on top search for, `browser.newtab.url` then right click on it and change it to what you want it to be, if you want a blank page, then just type in **about:blank**

Comment: I'd say, manual solution is prefereable instead of a commercial solution.

Answer (score 2):

might not be that easy (yes, even Firefox can be 'hijacked' :).

run **[MBAM](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php)** and scan for malware infections.

Answer (score 1):

First, like Molly said, scan for rubbish.

After that, one of these two may help you:
*[New Tab Homepage 0.4.1](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/777?src=api)* (then change the homepage to about:blank)
*[New Tab King 3.0.1](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10828?src=api)*

Answer (score 1):

1. Enter **`about:config`** into your location bar and hit
   <kbd>Enter</kbd>. [Ignore the fake warning if this is your first time
   there].
2. Type in **`browser.startup.homepage`** in the filter box.
3. Double click on the entry and put in **`about:blank`** if you want a blank page.

Comment: That is the browser startup homepage - not the page which is opening when you open a new tab.

Comment: @Idigas whoops looks like you are right.  Too much browser hopping today for my neural circuits.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution to provide the ability you're looking for is a Firefox add-on called *NewTabURL*:

[NewTabURL](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2221/)

> Select the default URL when new tabs are opened.
>
> The options are: "A blank page", "The home page", "The current page" or a user defined URL.
>
> When there is an URL in the clipboard, it is also possible to open automatically that URL in the new tab.

The two options Idigas mentioned behave a bit differently and may not have what you are looking for. *New Tab Homepage* loads your homepages(s) automatically in the new tab you open (which may not be the URL you want in the new tab). *New Tab King* opens up a menu of frequently used URL's, recently closed tabs, suggested sites. It has a lot of other doodads and configuration options such as sidebars, popup menus, etc. but I don't think you can just pick one URL for it to automatically load in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Click the middle button or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-click on the home page icon. No add-on required.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily.  Just install the featured add-on [My Homepage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/my-homepage/).

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Tools** → **Add-ons**. Simply disable all the add-ons. Then go to **Tools** → **Options** and make sure that the URL for your home page is set to something you like, such as Google. Your new tabs will now open as a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Enter about:config into your location bar and hit Enter. When you receive the security message, just click on "I'll be careful, I promise"
Type in browser.newtab in the filter box.
Double click on the entry and put in the URL you want (for example www.google.com)

Comment: There is no `browser.browser.newtab`; perhaps you meant `browser.newtab.url` as [answered](http://superuser.com/a/441917/117590) by [Max Jakobsson](http://superuser.com/users/142591/max-jakobsson)?